# Blazor Server app + external login Facebook: user name already taken

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've implemented Facebook external login followin https://hackernoon.com/how-to-implement-facebook-authentication-and-authorization-in-server-side-blazor-app-86p3zxj

I have scaffolded all Identity pages. Because every user should be added to a specific Role I have modified `Register.cshtml.cs` so that I can add all new users to a role:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
  returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
  ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
      _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

      // Add all new users to the User role
      await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, CustomRoles.User);

      var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
      code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
      var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
          "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
          pageHandler: null,
          values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
          protocol: Request.Scheme);

      await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
          $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

      if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
      {
        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email });
      }
      else
      {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
      }
    }
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
    }
  }

  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  return Page();
}
```

Because users who register and log in via external providers (e.g. facebook) should also be added to a specific role, I also added this part in the scaffolded `ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs` page:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
      returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
      ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
          _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

          // Add all new users to the User role
          await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, CustomRoles.User);

          var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
          code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
          var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
              "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
              pageHandler: null,
              values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
              protocol: Request.Scheme);

          await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
              $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

          if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
          {
            return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email });
          }
          else
          {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
          }
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
          ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
      }

      // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
      return Page();
    }
```

When going to https://localhost:44390/Identity/Account/Login it is possible to click the Facebook button under the "Use another service to log in":

[image]

This takes me to page: [https://localhost:44390/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F&handler=Callback#*=*](https://localhost:44390/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F&handler=Callback#_=_)

[image]

now when I click "Register" button I get:

[image]

This fails in the ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs`àfter the`var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user)`:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
      returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
      // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
      var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
      if (info == null)
      {
        ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information during confirmation.";
        return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
      }

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded) // <-- no success
```

My startup configureservices:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(
              Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

      services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => {
        // Require email confirmation (prevents registered users from logging in until their email is confirmed)
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

        // Password Settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        // Lockout settings.
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // User settings.
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; // True if the application requires each user to have their own, unique email, otherwise false.
      })
        .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();

      services.AddRazorPages();
      services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options =>
      {
        if (Env.IsDevelopment()) //only add details when debugging
        {
          options.DetailedErrors = true;
        }
      });
      services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();

      //services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
      services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
      {
        facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
        facebookOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents()
        {
          OnRemoteFailure = loginFailureHandler =>
          {
            var authProperties = facebookOptions.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(loginFailureHandler.Request.Query["state"]);
            loginFailureHandler.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login");
            loginFailureHandler.HandleResponse();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
          }
        };
      });
      services.AddAuthorization(config =>
      {
        config.AddPolicy(Policies.IsAdmin, Policies.IsAdminPolicy());
        config.AddPolicy(Policies.IsSuperUser, Policies.IsSuperUserPolicy());
        config.AddPolicy(Policies.IsUser, Policies.IsUserPolicy());
      });

      var emailCfg = Configuration.GetSection("EmailSenderOptions");
      services.Configure<EmailSenderOptions>(emailCfg);

      services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
      services.AddTransient<IReservationsService, ReservationsService>();
      services.AddTransient<IGeoService, GeoService>();
    }
```

I can understand that CreateAsync in ExternalLogin will fail when a user already exists, but how should this be modified? As the first time if the user doesn't exist and logs in via facebook, it should be created. When the user logs in again it should just log in.

Is this default scaffolded code incorrect or am I missing any configurations or modifying the externallogin in the wrong place?